# How can I have a moving pointer to a commit?

Tags: git

I'm currently designing a release system for a piece of software using Git. The system's structure is such that each release will have a corresponding commit on a different branch (or tag). Each of these "release commits" is a single commit whose previous commit is on the master branch.

It would be convenient for the repository to have a concept of the "last release", which would be a pointer to the last released commit.

Is there a Git object suitable for this?

- Tags are out, because it's not a good idea to change the commit to which a tag points.
- Branches are out too, since release N+1 is not made by making a commit to release N.

It should be possible to find the last release given the names of all the release commits, so if there isn't a convenient pointer object I'll just write a script to do that. But if there is a suitable object, I'd prefer to just use it.

Comment: Why not a release branch? Never commit to release branch, only merges from master is allowed. This way all commits in the release branch have a direct parent in master and latest release is simply HEAD

Comment: "Branches are out too, since release N+1 is not made by making a commit to release N." So what? Just move the branch pointer wherever you want. As long as people aren't basing work off it there's really no particular reason why you can't just move the branch directly from release N to release N+1. Otherwise I guess you could just use `update-ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Git's references are pointers to (a, one, single) commit.

The agreed-upon convention is that branches (`in refs/heads/*`) move, and tags (in `refs/tags/*`) don't.

The `refs/notes/` name-space is used by Git notes, and `refs/stash` is (the, single) stash reference.  The `refs/original/` space is used by `git filter-branch` but only sort of temporarily.  As far as I know all other names are available, if you want to avoid branch-names just to avoid them—but be aware that while you can *fetch* any name you like, the code to handle *pushes* knows which names are which, so if you want to update this via the push protocol, you should choose the branch name-space.